# Maven - dependency war unpack

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, war

I implemented a common module which is packages as war, say common_module.war. I need to use this common_module.war in another test application. In my local eclipse when i include common_module.war as dependency to the test application i am able access all the jsps & java classes of common_module.war in the test application. So far so good.

Now the problem is in order to deploy it on server. I uploaded the common_module.war to my company artifactory folder. And inluded that path in the repository paths. Now test application is not able to access the jsps of common_module.war.

What am i doing wrong here?

error is - i am including the jsp of common module in test application. There itself i can see red mark error jsp not found.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>test_group_id</groupId>
  <artifactId>test_artifact</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <name>test</name>
  <description>test</description>
 <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>central</id>
            <name>Maven Repository Switchboard</name>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>my_company_name</id>
            <url>path_to_my_company_artifactory</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
             <groupId>common_module_group_id</groupId>
                <artifactId>common_module_artifact</artifactId>
             <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <type>war</type>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/../package/dependencies/jbossews/webapps</outputDirectory>
                     <warSourceDirectory>/src/main/webapp</warSourceDirectory>
                      <webXml>src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\web.xml</webXml> 
                    <attachClasses>true</attachClasses>
                <classesClassifier>classes</classesClassifier>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                    <descriptors>
                        <descriptor>assembly.xml</descriptor>
                    </descriptors>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>   
        </plugins>
</project>
```

Comment: Has the artifact deployed correctly? Can you confirm this in the server log?

Comment: yes artifact deployed fine.

Comment: post your pom and error information.

Comment: When you build `test_artifact`, it contains JSP or not?

Comment: Why do you think that you can use a WAR file as a dependency like this at all?

Comment: @Steve C, i have a common Module which contains java classes as well as jsps. I need to use this common module UI in other projects as one of the menu options instead of implementing there. So thought of doing like this.

Comment: So your problem is in Eclipse? If so, which version and is it the Java EE version?

Comment: problem is not with eclipse. problem is with war. Solved with overlay feature

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you're trying to implement a `web-fragment`. This is a JAR file (not a WAR file) that can be included in a web application's WEB-INF/lib directory. It may contain the same components as a WAR file, including JSPs; it is just packaged differently.

The jar file should contain a `META-INF/web-fragment.xml` file and JSPs should be packaged in the `META-INF/resources` directory. The servlet container will treat JSP files in this directory as if they were in the root of your WAR file. `web-fragment.xml` is essentially a subset of the normal web.xml file.

This is Servlet 3.0+ feature.

Please see §8.2 and §10.5 of the Java Servlet Specification 3.0/3.1.

Comment: can i not achieve this with maven overlay feature?

Comment: Basically i want to access jsps & java classes of common moudle in the Test project. In my local overlay feature is working and able to access. but when i upload the common module war file to server only the problem

Answer (score 0):

war overlay feature helped me solving this issue. It is working fine now.